# Detect Current Django Site from Server Name

Tags: django

I'm looking to use the Django Sites framework to serve different content based on the current URL. For example, if the URL is http://siteA.example.com/, a call to Django's `Site.objects.get_current()` method will return a the Site object with a `url` value of `siteA.example.com`.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
django.contrib.sites.models
```

and use `get_current_site(request).id`

as explained in the **[documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#associating-content-with-multiple-sites)**.

Or you can use [**django-subdomains**](https://github.com/tkaemming/django-subdomains).

With this, you can use **subdomains.utils.reverse()** to identify the current subdomain being used.

Documentation **[here](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/utils.html#subdomains.utils.reverse)**.